# PHP if not function

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I can't get this piece of code to work correctly.

```
if($searchFuel != "all") {
    $queryString .= " AND carFuel = '$searchFuel'"; 
}
```

I can echo $searchFuel without any problem but it won't work within the If function.
It's the only one of the If functions that doesn't work, it's like it's just ignored.
Here is the full code.

```
$searchId = $_POST["searchValue"];
$searchType = $_POST["searchType"];
$searchBrand = $_POST["searchBrand"];
$searchFuel = $_POST["searchFuel"];

$queryString = "SELECT * FROM cars";

if(!empty($searchId)) {

    $queryString .= " WHERE (carBrand LIKE '%$searchId%' OR carModel LIKE '%$searchId%')";

    if($searchType != "all") {
        $queryString .= " AND carType = '$searchType'"; 
    }

    if($searchBrand != "all") {
        $queryString .= " AND carBrand = '$searchBrand'";
    }

    if($searchFuel != "all") {
        $queryString .= " AND carFuel = '$searchFuel'"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: `var_dump($searchFuel)` before the `if` statement. What does it output?

Comment: What *does* it do instead?

Comment: does `echo $searchFuel;` outputs any white spaces or new lines after / before `all`

Comment: I tried "echo var_dump($searchFuel)" it echoes out "NULL".

Comment: Well, that would be the problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: the name of the input ought not to be `searchFuel`  if you var_dump($_POST); you'll get the real name it's receiving from html input name

Comment: How do you `echo` it when it's `NULL`

Comment: Sorry, i echoed out the wrong variable, this is what it says: string(4) "all"

Comment: "all" only has three letters, not (4). There's some invisible character in there.

Comment: The output of $searchFuel would be "Diesel" and if i type echo $searchFuel it's exactly what it echoes so the variable is being posted and can be echoed out but won't work in the If function.

Comment: Total catch for @deceze . You have some whitespaces. Where does the input come from? Predefined values of text field? Are you entering spaces after/before the string? You can fix that by trimming the posted values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seem to be correct.
This is probably because your `$_POST["searchFuel"]` is empty. Check it before assign your variable `$searchFuel`